Shopify GraphQL API add category taxonomy to product
I am trying to create a Shopify product with Shopify latest GraphQL API (version 2024-10). I cannot find a way to attach category taxonomy to it. For example, I would like to mark a book as sci-fi genre. Categories taxonomies can be found here: https://shopify.github.io/product-taxonomy/releases/unstable/?categoryId=gid%3A%2F%2Fshopify%2FTaxonomyCategory%2Fme-1
Is there any way to achieve it through the GraphQL API? I clearly see an option to add custom attributes and a category, but not standard taxonomies.
